# How to send bulk notifications based on conditions in Laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have a project on Laravel-5.8. I am trying to send bulk notifications to emails based on conditions:

```
public function employee_notifications()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id; 
    $employeeCode               = Auth::user()->employee_code;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    
    $employeeemail = DB::table('hr_gradings')->select('email')->where('respondent_id', $userId)->get();
    $condition1 = DB::table('hr_gradings')->where('employee_type', 0)->get();
$condition2 = DB::table('hr_gradings')->where('employee_type', 1)->get();
  
    
  DB::beginTransaction(); 
    try {   

    $details = [
        'sent_to' => '',
        'sent_by' => $userI'',
        'subject' => 'Mid-Year Self-Review Approved by : ' .$userFirstName .' for '.$reviewperiod,
        'greeting' => 'Dear '.$employeefirstname . ' '. $employeelastname . ',',
        'body' =>  'Some text. ' . 'Proceed to see review comments .',
        'line1' => 'some text 2',            
        'line2' => 'Proceed to see review comments .',
        'thanks' => 'Thank you!',            
        'actionText' => 'My Self-Review',
        'actionURL' => url('http://localhost:8888/employees/testing1'),            
        'employee_email' => '',


                
    ];


                Notification::route('mail', $details['employee_email'])
                ->notify(new \App\Notifications\Testing($details));       
        DB::commit();
        Session::flash('success', 'successfully');
        return redirect()->back();
     } catch (Exception $exception) {

DB::rollback();

            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return redirect()->back();
    }                    
}
```

What I have so far is for a single user email.

If

`$condition = DB::table('hr_gradings')->where('employee_type', 0)->get();`

it should send notifications to all in

`$employeeemail = DB::table('hr_gradings')->select('email')->where('respondent_id', $userId)->get();`

where employee_type = 0

and use this action url:    `'actionURL' => url('http://localhost:8888/employees/testing1'),`

But if

`$condition = DB::table('hr_gradings')->where('employee_type', 1)->get();`

it should send notifications to all in

`$employeeemail = DB::table('hr_gradings')->select('email')->where('respondent_id', $userId)->get();`

where employee_type = 1

and use this action url:    `'actionURL' => url('http://localhost:8888/employees/testing2'),`

How do I achieve this and also get this employee_email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Loop the code using for each



foreach $condition2 as $bulkemail
{
   //insert here the sending email code
   //replace  'sent_to' => '',

   'sent_to' => '$bulkemail->email',
}
```